# The equation $ab+ba=0, a=a^*, b=b^*$ in a $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Does the equation $ab+ba=0$,  $a=a^*, b=b^*$ in a  $C^*$ algebra implies that ab=0?
What is the universal  unital $C^*$ algebra subject to the above relations  with boundedness condition $|a|=|b|=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't. For instance take
$$
a=\begin{bmatrix} -1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\qquad\qquad b=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Then $a=a^*$, $b=b^*$, $\|a\|=\|b\|=1$, and
$$
ab+ba=\begin{bmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
I don't know about the universal algebra they generate. But $C^*(a,b)=M_2(\mathbb C)$. And we can replace $1$ and $-1$ with $t$, and you get, for any compact space $X$,  $C^*(a(t),b(t))=M_2(C(X))$. But it doesn't look hard to find bigger matrices satisfying this relations, so the universal algebra looks like it should be huge.

Comment: Thank  you  for  your  answer.  I  would  appreciate if  you  answer or  comment on the  following post  too

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4734803/a-question-on-disjointness-preserving-operator