# A question on disjointness preserving operator

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

In "Disjointness preserving operators on $C^*$  algebras"  by  Manfred  Wolff, Arch. Math 62, 248-253, 1994 it is  presented the concept of  zero  divisor preserving map as  follows:

Let  $A$  and  $B$  be  two  $C^*$  algebras. A symmetric  bounded  linear  operator  $\phi:A\to B$ is  disjointness preserving  if  $xy=0,  x=x^*,  y=y^*$  implies that $\phi(x)\phi(y)=0$.
In  example  2.2 it is  written  that  every  Jordan  *  homomorphism is  a  disjointness preserving operator.

What is  a  proof  for this fact?

I tried to prove it via  points  in the  following post but the answer to the post  shows that  my  method  does not  work.

[The equation $ab+ba=0, a=a^*, b=b^*$ in a $C^*$ algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4734565/the-equation-abba-0-a-a-b-b-in-a-c-algebra)

I had  intention to prove it via the following:  Let $\phi:A\to B$ be  a  symetric  Jordan homomorphism. Assume that $xy=0$  for  self  adjoint  $x,y$
Then  we  have  $xy+yx=0$ then  we have  $\phi (x)\phi(y)+\phi(y)\phi(x)=0$. Moreover  $a=\phi(x)$  and  $b=\phi (y)$  are self adjoint  elements  satisfying $ab+ba=0$ but according to the  answer to the  above  post  this  does not imply that $ab=0$

So how  can one  prove the assertion of  example  2.2 in the Wolff paper?

**Note:** A  symmetric linear operator  is  a  linear map $\phi:A\to B$  with  $\phi(x^*)=(\phi(x))^*$. A  aJordan Homomorphism is  a  linear map satisfying one of the following equivalent conditions:

1. $\phi(x^2)=(\phi(x))^2$
2. $\phi(xy+yx)=\phi(x)\phi(y)+\phi(y)\phi(x)$

Comment: It might be useful to include the definition of Jordan homomorphism. Later in your post, you speak about 'symmetric' Jordan homomorphism. What does symmetric mean here?

Comment: @J.DeRo  Symmetric means:  $\phi(x^*)=(\phi (x))^*$

Comment: @J.DeRo thanks for your attention. I will revise the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a Jordan homomorphism, $\phi(yxy)=\phi(y)\phi(x)\phi(y)$.  Following is a proof from I.N. Herstein, Jordan homomorphisms, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc., 81 (1956), 331–341.
[image: Proof of Lemma]

Now, getting back to the problem at hand.  Since $xy=0$ then $yxy=xyx=0$ and it follows from the above that $bab=aba=0$.  You've already shown that $ab+ba=0$ so
$$
\begin{align}
(ab-ba)^2 &= abab-abba-baab+baba\\ &= abab - (-ba)ba - (-ab)ab + baba\\ &= abab + baba + abab + baba\\ &= 2a(bab) + 2(bab)a = 0
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore, $(ab-ba)^* = b^* a^* - a^* b^* = ba - ab = -(ab-ba)$ so
$$(ab-ba)^* (ab-ba) = -(ab-ba)^2 = 0$$
Now, in a $C^*$-algebra, $\|u^*u\| = \|u^*\| \|u\|$, so letting $u=ab-ba$ it follows that $\|ab-ba\| = 0$, so $ab - ba = 0$.  You already proved that $ab+ba=0$ so adding the two identities and dividing by two you get $ab=0$.$\Box$

Comment: Thank  you  for the beautiful lemma  by  Herstein. But in the line starting  with $(ab-ba)^2$ how do  you  conclude the last "=0"?

Comment: @AliTaghavi: See edit for clarification.

Comment: Thank  you very  much  for  your  very interesting answer